# Topological K-theory of Bohr compactification of real numbers

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, at.algebraic-topology

I am interested in the 
K-theory of the Bohr compactification $\mathbb{R}_B$ of the real numbers.

Do we have $K_0(C(\mathbb{R}_B))$ isomorphic to $K_1(C(\mathbb{R}_B))$ ?

More generally, what do we know about these groups ? 
Have they been determined ?

Comment: What is $C(-)$?

Comment: By $C(X)$, I mean the algebra of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$.